# binding elements of a certain class dynamically after creation

Tags: jquery, event-handling, keypress, dynamically-generated

I dynamically create textareas with the class `arindic` in `document.ready()`.

Then after their dynamic generation is over, and still within the `document.ready()` routine, I bind those elements with the `keypress` event like this:

```
$('.arindic').bind('keypress', function(evt){
   // do lots of stuff
});
```

but it's not working. I know the function that's "doing lots of stuff" is working fine because at the bottom of `document.ready()` I have this:

```
 $('.arindic').keypress(function(evt){ // do lots of stuff // });
```

and this works fine for textareas that were statically already present on the page. Is there something wrong with the way I'm binding the dynamic elements? Instead of `.bind()` I also tried `.on()` and `.live()` but to no avail.

Comment: `.on` didn't worked ? Are you able to reproduce it in a small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: I'm guessing you bound `.on` to a dynamicly created element, the example below will definitely work for all `.arindic` textareas

Comment: Binding to a dynamically created element works for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/m9ZQc/4/.

Answer (score 2):

you're best bet is to use `.on()` to bind to a static element and bubble up to the dynamically created element.

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.arindic', function(event)
{
    // do lots of stuff
});
```

using document to bind to is not a good thing, I'd change this to the highest level element that `.arindic` is contained within that is static, and allow this event to bubble up from there.

Comment: You could bind it on the `body` too or on the elements container.